# Module not found on debian VM but working on Windows workstation

Tags: node.js, typescript

I my company, we are developing an app in nodeJS with TypeScript. My colleagues work on Windows environment. I want to deploy the app on a Debian VM. Everything works on Windows but not on Debian. All the imports of the project are rejected at build.

Here two of 360 errors, which are all the same :

```
src/data/index.ts:1:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './database-selector.bootstrap' or its corresponding type declarations.
1 export * from "./database-selector.bootstrap";

src/data/index.ts:2:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './database.interface' or its corresponding type declarations.
2 export * from "./database.interface";
```

It seems to be linked to the path but I don't understand what is wrong.

Can you help me to understand?

Comment: please provide the working directory tree in the vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about the filenames. We don't know what appened but some imports contained uppercases and the files were named in lowercase. In Windows, everything worked but not on Linux. We fixed this issue by rename files and update the imports strings.